# Trying to get buy and sell fee for any BEP20/ERC20

Tags: uniswap, fees, pancakeswap

I'm trying to understand how https://honeypot.is/?address=0x317a214777a04576b0287fc8abc98738b27815c8 works.

I'll link all info from the BSC checker but is almost the same for ETH

They are using a custom contract: https://bscscan.com/address/0x5bf62ec82af715ca7aa365634fab0e8fd7bf92c7

calling the method: 0xd66383cb

What I want to understand is how that contract may test for token fees.

I've read that you can make static calls to test this kind of thing but I can't manage to find any guidelines to start coding that.

Any help on understanding how this may work will be welcomed :)

*Sorry if this is not the best quality post, is my first post, and I'm not a native English speacker.*